# mySQL Order by number query, not ordering by whole number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have constructed a query here using mysql workbench:

```
USE wcms;
SELECT PLA_FNAME, PLA_LNAME, PLA_GS FROM player ORDER BY PLA_GS DESC;
```

It then displays these results:

[image]

As you can see, it is ordering the Player goals scored column by 9 being the highest value, not 20. What would be the best way to order this column by the whole number so 20 is at the top of the list?

Comment: What is the type of the `PLA_GS` column?

Comment: You are obviously using the wrong data type - this happens when numbers are put into _text_ data types. Make it a fitting numeric data type, and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 9):

Try this order statement

```
ORDER BY PLA_GS + 0 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

The cast is the appropriate solution, this could work for the lazy:

```
ORDER BY PLA_GS+0 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY Cast(PLA_GS as int) DESC
```

Query:

```
USE wcms;
SELECT PLA_FNAME, PLA_LNAME, PLA_GS FROM player ORDER BY Cast(PLA_GS as int) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This "sorting error"(1) happens, when using text data types for storing numbers. The command

```
DESCRIBE player;
```

shows, amongst other information, which data types are used for each column and will probably show some text data type like `varchar`in this case.

If you have access to changing the table structure, use a numerical data type for the numbers instead, like `int`. This will solve your sorting problem.

Additionally you'll save some space on your HDD and speed up your query. `int`s require far less memory than saving numbers in ascii format (which is what happens when using eg. `varchar`), and comparing integers is much faster than comparing (probably long) text elements.

If you don't have access to change the table structure, use the casting trick, already provided in the other answers.

(1) Not actually an error. Just character-wise sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone for your help. The issue was the column was the wrong datatype as previously stated in a comment. This was fixed by setting to column to an int:

```
ALTER TABLE PLAYER MODIFY COLUMN PLAY_GS INT(3);
```

Then running the query:

```
SELECT PLA_FNAME, PLA_LNAME, PLA_GS FROM player ORDER BY PLA_GS DESC;
```

Gave me the results correctly ordered.